# How to pass variables through url

Tags: php

I am facing problems when passing variables from one page to another using url.

```
echo '<a href="pass1.php?myNumber=1">Send variables via URL!</a>';
```

In pass1.php

```
$b=$_GET['myNumber'];
echo $b;
```

The output is:-

> Notice: Undefined index: myNumber in
>   C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\srinath\pass1.php on line 2

Comment: we need whole code mate !

Comment: @AncientGeek What do you need more?

Comment: Cannot see any problem in the code you posted. We need more code. Check in your url if you can see `myNumber=1` or not ?

Comment: @Mr.Alien just now some one edited and the url became visible :P

Comment: Do you see `myNumber` in your URL?

Comment: Can you post the result of `var_dump($_REQUEST)` ?

Comment: Btw did u click the link or you just calling the `pass1.php` directly ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with your href=""

You should specify the protocol (which is probably `http://`) and then the link. Though you can use `?myNumber=23`, it appends to the current page URL whose result might be unexpected...

Answer (score -1):

check variable before you use.

```
if(isset($_GET['myNumber']))
{
$b=$_GET['myNumber'];
echo $b;
}
```